# jQuery event target repitition

Tags: jquery

I have simple a function that will look for a specific class ('.clickable') and add a class when it's clicked ('.last-clicked). I want to remove the ('.last-clicked') class from all other existing elements so there is only one item with that class.

```
$('.clickable').click(function(event) { 
    $('.clickable').removeClass('last-clicked');
    $(event.target).addClass('last-clicked');
});
```

My function works but it seems silly to refer to $('.clickable') in the wrapper and the function. Is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: Ehh, not really. You can use `this` to target the element that you clicked, but since you want to remove the class from all elements with the `clickable` class, you're doing it the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only using `last-clicked` for these elements try:

```
$('.clickable').click(function(event) { 
    $('.last-clicked').removeClass('last-clicked');
    $(event.target).addClass('last-clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the DOM isn't going to have clickable elements added or removed you can do this:

```
var $clickable = $('.clickable');
$clickable.click(function(event) { 
    $clickable.removeClass('last-clicked');
    $(event.target).addClass('last-clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/)...

```
//you can swap out event.target with this, if you like
$('.clickable').click(function(event) { 
    $('.clickable').removeClass('last-clicked').end().find(event.target).addClass('last-clicked');
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/eU37H/3/